# data group and sum in mar to feb of one year

Tags: oracle, group-by

My data is like

```
200201  0
200202  2
200203  0
200204  4
200205  0
200206  0
200207  0
200208  0
200209  0
200210  0
200211  0
200212  5
200301  0
200302  0
200303  0
200304  0
200305  2
200306  0
200307  0
200308  0
200309  0
200310  0
200311  3
200312  0
200401  0
200402  0
```

I want output

```
2002FEB 2
MAR2002TOFEB2003    9
MAR2003TOFEB2004    5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this grouping query:

```
select 'MAR '||(year-1)||' to FEB '||year period, sum(val) sum_val
  from (select distinct substr(mth, 1, 4) year from data) y 
  join data d on y.year-1 ||'02' < d.mth and d.mth <= y.year || '02'
  group by year order by year
```

Output:

```
PERIOD                SUM_VAL
--------------------  ----------
MAR 2001 to FEB 2002           2
MAR 2002 to FEB 2003           9
MAR 2003 to FEB 2004           5
```

Test data:

```
create table data (mth varchar2(6), val number(3));
insert into data values (200201, 0);
insert into data values (200202, 2); 
insert into data values (200203, 0); 
insert into data values (200204, 4); 
insert into data values (200205, 0); 
insert into data values (200206, 0); 
insert into data values (200207, 0); 
insert into data values (200208, 0); 
insert into data values (200209, 0); 
insert into data values (200210, 0); 
insert into data values (200211, 0); 
insert into data values (200212, 5); 
insert into data values (200301, 0); 
insert into data values (200302, 0); 
insert into data values (200303, 0); 
insert into data values (200304, 0); 
insert into data values (200305, 2); 
insert into data values (200306, 0); 
insert into data values (200307, 0); 
insert into data values (200308, 0); 
insert into data values (200309, 0); 
insert into data values (200310, 0); 
insert into data values (200311, 3); 
insert into data values (200312, 0);
insert into data values (200401, 0); 
insert into data values (200402, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  year_month CHAR(6),
  val        INT
);
```

(Insert your data)

**Query**:

```
SELECT 'MAR' || Year || 'TOFEB' || ( Year + 1 ) AS range,
       SUM( val ) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE( year_month, 'YYYYMM' ), -2 ) ) AS year,
         val
  FROM   data
)
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;
```

**Output**:

```
RANGE            TOTAL
---------------- -----
MAR2001TOFEB2002     2 
MAR2002TOFEB2003     9 
MAR2003TOFEB2004     5
```